# combineLatest emit only when one of the streams changes

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a stream with frequent values and one with slower ones. I want to combine them, but only emit a value when the slower one emits. So `combineLatest` doesn't work.
Like so:

```
a1
a2
b1
(a2,b1)
a3
a4
a5
b2
(a5,b2)
```

Currently I'm doing it like follows, is there a cleaner way?

```
withLatest[A,B](fast : Observable[A], slow : Observable[B]): Observable[(A,B)] =
  Observable({ o =>
    var last : A
    fast.subscribe({a => last = a})
    slow.subscribe({b => o.onNext((last,b))})
  })
```

**edit**: This operator is now in Rx and is called [withLatestFrom](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/2760).

Comment: Sorry. My previous answer is wrong. I have deleted it.

Comment: I asked exactly this question on RxJava's issue tracker: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/405 But the answers weren't satisfying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a combinator I have called "combinePrev", which doesn't exist in the API but turns out to be very necessary in many situations. `sample` operator comes close, but it doesn't combine the two streams. [I've also missed "combinePrev" in RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/335). It turns out, the implementation of "combinePrev" ("withLatest") is simple and just depends on map and switch:

```
withLatest[A,B](fast : Observable[A], slow : Observable[B]): Observable[(A,B)] = {
  val hotSlow = slow.publish.refCount
  fast.map({a => hotSlow.map({b => (a,b)})}).switch
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/2orcypoz/3/) example of the same operator implemented in RxJS.

While the operator is not in Rx, you can use an implicit class so you can use `slow.withLatest(fast)`:

```
implicit class RXwithLatest[B](slow: Observable[B]) {
  def withLatest[A](fast : Observable[A]) : Observable[(A,B)] = /* see above */
}
```

Note: `slow` must be `hot`. If `slow` is a cold Observable, `withLatest` doesn't work.

Comment: Nice to see I'm not the only one. Hope this gets added to RxJava. However I guess that in your current answer `B` should be `slow` and `A` should be `fast`?

Comment: Corrected your scala and variable names, but otherwise works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, B should be slow and A fast, sorry for not bringing it to the context. And yeah it should be added to RxJava as a @Beta operator, check this github issue: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/405

Comment: Added a note: `slow must be hot`

Comment: Since slow is hot, looks `val hotSlow = slow.publish.refCount` can be removed.

Comment: `val hotSlow = slow.publish.refCount` should stay since it makes `slow` hot, not matter if `slow` was hot or cold before.

Comment: This operator is now implemented in RxJS as `withLatestFrom`: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md Should come to Rx JVM soon, but no one is assigned yet to implement it.

Comment: withLatestFrom is now an experimental operator in RxJava in the most recent release: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.0.7