# RxJava: how to emulate withLatestFrom?

Tags: rx-java

According to the documentation, [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) is missing from the Java implementation (which is subtly different from `combineLatest`). Any idea on how to emulate that? [image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203435/combinelatest-emit-only-when-one-of-the-streams-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `a` as the main observable and `b` as the 'latest from' observable, this pseudo-java8 lambda should do what you want:

```
a.publish(a' -> b.switchMap(y -> a'.map(x -> x + y)))
```

This first publishes `a` as `a'`, which allows it to be subscribed to repeatedly without restarting the stream. Then, each time a new item from `b` is emitted, it resubscribes to the ongoing stream of `a`, which combines the latest output of `b` with each output of `a`.

You could easily wrap that as an implementation of RxJava's `Transformer`, like this (also semi-pseudo, so check my syntax):

```
 public class WithLatestFrom<T, U, V> implements Transformer<T, V> {
   private final Func2<T, U, V> function;
   private final Observable<U> latest;

   private WithLatestFrom<T, U, V>(final Observable<U> latest, Func2<T, U, V> function) {
     this.function = function;
     this.latest = latest;
   }

   public static <T, U, V> WithLatestFrom<T, U, V> with(
       final Observable<U> latest, Func2<T, U, V> function) {
     return new WithLatestFrom<T, U, V>(latest, function);
   }

   @Override
   public Observable<V> call(final Observable<T> source) {
     return source.publish((publishedSource) -> latest.switchMap((y) ->
         publishedSource.map((x) -> function.call(x, y)));
   }

}
```

Then you can reuse it in your code like:

```
a.compose(WithLatestFrom.with(b, (x, y) -> x + y));
```

Comment: Also, I just found out that 1.0.7 has an experimental withLatestFrom operator: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.0.7 :)

Comment: Yup, interesting solution anyway! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some very simple and naive implementation is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T, U, V> Observable<T> combineLatestFrom(
  Observable<U> o1,
  Observable<V> o2,
  Func2<U, V, T> f) {

    final Object nothing = new Object();
    return Observable.create(s -> {

        AtomicReference<V> val2 = new AtomicReference<V>((V) nothing);

        o1.subscribe(v -> {
          val2.getAndUpdate(current -> {
            if (current != nothing) {
              s.onNext(f.call(v, current));
            }
            return current;
          });   
        }, s::onError, s::onCompleted);

        o2.subscribe(val2::set, s::onError);

    });
}
```

And this method can be used like this:

```
combineLatestFrom(numbers, letters, (n, l) -> n + l)
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If in here numbers and letters are the Observables from the marble diagram -> the result will be as expected.

Comment: What's the purpose of `val1`? Your example could be simplified since `val1` seems useless?